# OpenGL (ES) -- Polygons disappear temporarily when new objects added to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, graphics, opengl-es, arraylist

In an OpenGL ES 1.x Android application, I generate a circle (from triangles) and then translate it about one hundred times to form a level. Everything works except when a certain event occurs that causes about 15 objects to be immediately added to the arraylist that stores the circles' coordinates. When this event happens 2+ times quickly, all the circles in the list disappear for about 1/5th of a second. Besides this, the circles animate smoothly.

The program  runs well as a java SE app using the same synchronization techniques, and I have tried a half a dozen or so other synch techniques to no avail, so I feel the problem is the openGL implementation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the list is being modified under your nose? It sounds like you need to do any modification to this list on the OpenGL thread. Try `Activity.postOnUiThread(Runnable)`, where `Runnable` implements your own code. Possibly.

Comment: I have a logic backend in another thread that's several thousand lines of code, and it would be difficult to migrate this one list away from there. As for synch: I've used the synch blocks, CopyOnWriteArrayLists, created deep copy of the array in the opengl function (as a buffer),... . No tricks or one-line fixes?

Comment: All you have to do is create a runnable, passing in the information to be written, and then just post the runnable. Do that everywhere you modify the array. Create a function for it, even. It's not hard, even with a backend. It sounds like if you're modifying GL state out of the UI thread, you're going to suffer in the long term anyway.

Comment: As it turns out, the problem was the getCircleSize method returned an integer, and I needed a float. Three hours of my life spent to change int to float. But its worth it, it always is.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really have to store the vertex data in client memory? If you don't modify it, I suggest you use a VBO instead. Just upload it into graphics memory once, then draw from there. It will be much faster (not requiring you to send all the vertex data for each draw), and I'm pretty sure you won't run into the problem you described.

Transformations can be done as much as you like, then you only have to give the draw command for each instance of your circle.

Comment: the VBO looks very useful. User input causes modifications on the objects (their vertex data and other things), and the objects cause modifications on other objects. Mixing it together doesn't seem right. Thanks guy.